# How do I return an array of objects that only contains a certain object in an array for Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object called actors:

```
const actors =  [{
   "name": "John Doe",
   "rating": 1234,
   "alternative_name": null,
   "objectID": "551486300"
},
{
   "name": "Jane Doe",
   "rating": 4321,
   "alternative_name": "Monica Anna Maria Bellucci",
   "objectID": "551486310"
}];
```

I specifically want to get the name and the ratings of the actors.
I tried getting it by making a function called actorNameRating, but my code does not work.

```
const nameAndRating = function() {

    const actorName = nameAndRating.filter(name);
    return actorName;

    const actorRating = nameAndRating.filter(rating);
    return actorRating;
 };
```

Comment: You cannot return twice from a function. After first return the code below will not be executed.

Comment: What output do you want, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** a function and return only name and rating:

```js
const actors =  [{
   "name": "John Doe",
   "rating": 1234,
   "alternative_name": null,
   "objectID": "551486300"
},
{
   "name": "Jane Doe",
   "rating": 4321,
   "alternative_name": "Monica Anna Maria Bellucci",
   "objectID": "551486310"
}];

const nameAndRating = function() {

   return actors.map(actor => ({
     name : actor.name,
     rating : actor.rating 
   }))
 };

console.log(nameAndRating())
```

Answer (score 1):

any thing after the return will not be executed you can return both values as one string then separate it 
for example :

```
const nameAndRating = function() {
    const actorName = nameAndRating.filter(name);
    const actorRating = nameAndRating.filter(rating);
    return actorName+","+actorRating;
 };
```

or any other way you find better for you to use